# Find the possible real values of $(x,y)$ satisfying $\sin x+\cos x=\frac{y^2-2y+4}{y^2+2y+4}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Find the possible real values of $(x,y)$ satisfying $\sin x+\cos x=\frac{y^2-2y+4}{y^2+2y+4}$.

I could not solve this question after trying many times.How can two variables be solved with one equation?Please help me.

Its answer is $(2n\pi+\frac{\pi}{4}\pm\arccos\frac{k}{\sqrt2},\frac{1+k\pm\sqrt{(k-3)(1-3k)}}{1-k});$ where $k\in [\frac{1}{3},\sqrt2]-\left\{1\right\}$ and $(2n\pi+\frac{\pi}{4}\pm\frac{\pi}{4},0)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

Let $u=\dfrac{y^2-2y+4}{y^2+2y+4}$

$\iff y^2(u-1)+2y(u+1)+4u-4=0$

As $y$ is real, the discriminant  $4\{(u+1)^2-4(u-1)^2\}\ge0$

$\iff3u^2-10u+3\le0\iff (u-3)\left(u-\dfrac13\right)\le0\iff\dfrac13\le u\le3$

Now $\cos x+\sin x=\sqrt2\sin\left(\dfrac\pi4+x\right)\implies-\sqrt2\le\cos x+\sin x\le\sqrt2$

So, we need $\dfrac13\le\dfrac{y^2-2y+4}{y^2+2y+4}=\cos x+\sin x\le\sqrt2$

Now set $$\dfrac{y^2-2y+4}{y^2+2y+4}=\cos x+\sin x=k$$  with $\dfrac13\le k\le\sqrt2$

Comment: @diya, As $$\dfrac{y^2-2y+4}{y^2+2y+4}=\cos x+\sin x$$

Comment: I understood,thank you@lab bhattacharjee.

Answer (score 2):

Hint...set both sides equal to $k$.
The left hand side can be written as $\sqrt{2}\cos(x-\frac{\pi}{4})$ so that means that $|k|\leq \sqrt{2}$.
Now consider the other half of the equation as a quadratic in $y$ which must have real roots, and this will give a further set of conditions for $k$. There is also a horizontal asymptote to consider....
I hope this helps.